# Magmi truncating German text (Special Characters)

Tags: magento-1.8, magmi, csv

I am importing some attributes in German and also exported the file as CSV with UTF-8. It is truncating some of the German words.

Content of CSV -

header - sku,affiliate_category_de,type,attribute_set

Text which is getting Truncated -

"Wohnen & Lifestyle > Büro - Getting truncated to - Wohnen & Lifestyle > B"

"Wohnen & Lifestyle > Bar & Küche - Getting truncated to - Wohnen & Lifestyle > Bar & K"

"Geschenke > Für Kinder - Getting truncated to - Geschenke > F"

These values are prepoulated in a Global dropdown attribute.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used Openoffice Calc and saved as CSV with Unicode (UTF-8) and it worked fine.